# LINQ Query comparing two lists with sublist

Tags: c#, linq

I'm making a game that has a crafting system. I'm trying to get a list of recipes, but only show the ones the player has enough of in their inventory. I'm having difficulty figuring out this query. Here are my stripped down classes:

```
public class GameItem
{
    public string itemName;
    public int quantityHeld;
}

public class GameItemRecipe : GameItem
{
    public GameItemIngredient[] giiIngredients;
}

public class GameItemIngredient : GameItem
{        
    public int quantityNeeded;
}
```

So I have a list of GameItems; that is the player's inventory. Then I have a separate list of Recipes that the Player knows. The Recipes have a sub list of the ingredients required to make it. So I want to get the list of recipes that have enough items in the inventory. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why do `GameItemRecipe` and `GameItemIngredient` inherit `GameItem`? They seem unrelated.

Comment: As @Sweeper says, it seems these classes aren't well thought out. The `GameItem` class containing the quantityHeld seems more appropriate for an `Inventory` class. The `GameItemIngredient` class seems like it should encapsulate `GameItem`s rather than inherit from it.

Comment: I disagree, I think they are well thought out. Recipes, Ingredients, Equipment, etc... are all items in the game. They all have many properties in common such as name, and quantity held. Why wouldn't they inherit from GameItem? Keep in mind, this is not my game's full structure. I just stripped it down to make it easier for stack overflow. I can't imagine you all want to sift through all my code.

Comment: Interfaces would be much better suited for your case.

Comment: Plus, held quantity should not be a property of the object itself. This information belongs to the container (as said by Will, some kind of inventory).

Answer (score 0):

```
var recipes = new List<GameItemRecipe>();
var inventory = new List<GameItem>();

var possibleRecipes = recipes.Where(rec => r.giiIngredients.
                          All(i => ing.quantityNeeded <= inventory.
                          FirstOrDefault(gi => gi.itemName== ing.itemName)?.quantityHeld));
```

This query takes all of your recipes, where for all of the ingredients the quantity need field is smaller or equals the quanitity held field of the game item with the same item name in your inventory lsit of game items.

Comment: The Inventory is a sequence of GameItems: some of them are GameItemIngredients, some of them may not. Are you sure that every item in the Inventory that has a name that matches the Ingredient is a GameItemIngredient?

Comment: If there is no matching name, then `FirstOrDefault(...)?.QuantityHeld` will be null. Is it possible to  compare `quantityNeeded <= null`?

Answer (score 0):

So you have a `Player`, and this Player has an `Inventory`, which is a sequence of `GameItems`. Some of these GameItems may be `GameItemIngredients`. You didn't specify that all GameItems in the Inventory are GameItemIngredients, so it might be that some GameItems in the Inventory are not GameItemIngredients.

Furthermore, the Player knows a sequence of `GameItemRecipes`. To make one of these recipes, the player needs the `GameItemIngredients` that are mentioned in the recipe.

The Player needs to know which Recipes he can make. In other words: for which Recipes does the Player have enough Ingredients.

```
IEnumerable<GameItem> inventory = ...
IEnumerable<GameItemRecipe> recipes = ...
```

From this you can extract all Ingredients that the Player has in his Inventory:

```
IEnumerable<GameItemIngredient> ingredients = inventory.OfType<GameItemRecipe>();
```

> Requirement: Give me all Recipes that the Player can make; which are all Recipes that the Player has all Ingredients for.

Every GameItemIngredient has a property `RequiredQuantity`. I assume that every Recipe will have unique names for the GameItemIngredients that are needed to make the Recipe.

Simply said: if you need two Potatoes to make Recipe "Mashed Potatoes", then the Ingredients list of the Recipe will contain only one Ingredient with the Name "Potato". This Ingredient will have quantity 2. So you will not have the Ingredient Potato twice in your Recipe.

Furthermore I assume, that you don't do sub-classing in your Recipes: if your Recipe requires an "Apple", and you have a "Granny Smith" in your Inventory, then alas, you can't make the Recipe, even though a "Granny Smith" is an "Apple".

> A Recipe can be made, if all Ingredients of the Recipe are in the Ingredients of the Inventory AND the `QuantityNeeded` <= `QuantityHeld`.

So for every Recipe we will need to check whether the Ingredients are in the Inventory. To make this efficient, we will make a Dictionary of the Ingredients that are in the Inventory. Key is the `ItemName` of the Ingredient; Value is the `QuantityHeld`

```
var ingredientQuantities = ingredients.ToDictionary(
    ingredient => ingredient.ItemName,
    ingredient => ingredient.QuantityHeld);
```

Consider to use an EqualityComparer if "Apple" is the same ingredient as "apple"

The ItemName of every ingredient of a Recipe should be a key in the Dictionary, AND the QuantityNeeded <= QuantityHeld (= value in the Dictionary)

```
var recipesThatCanBeMade = recipes
   .Where(recipe => !recipe.Ingredients.All(ingredient =>
       ingredientQuantities.TryGetValue(ingredient.ItemName, out int quantityHeld)
       && ingredient.QuantityNeeded <= quantityHeld)
```

In words: from every recipe in the sequence of recipes, keep only those recipes where

- **ALL** ingredients have an ItemName that is a key in the dictionary,
- **AND** have a QuantityNeeded that is smaller or equal to the QuantityHeld that is the corresponding value in the Dictionary.